# Permutations on the set of natural numbers.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I was in a course of Abstract Algebra, and the teacher asked some interesting questions at the end of a course on the material we had seen. I found the answer to the first question, but the other two leave me perplexed. Could you give me your opinion on the answers (2) and (3)?

**(1)** Is the function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $ such that $$f= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & ...\\
f(1) & f(2) & f(3) & f(4) & ...
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & ...\\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & ...
\end{pmatrix}$$ is a permutation?

**(2)** Is there a function $ f \in S_E$ with $E = \mathbb{N}$  that is factorisable into disjoint cycle of infinite order such that $\mid \{n \in \mathbb{N} : f(n) \not= n\}\mid < \infty$ ?

**Definitions :**

1. $S_E$ is the set of all permutation of $E$.
2. Let the set $E \not= \emptyset$. We say that a map $f : E \to E$ has an inverse function, if there is a mapping $g : E \to E$ such that both composition $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are the application identity for each $x \in E$. We say that $f$ is a permutation (bijection) of $E$ .

**(3)** Does the subset of functions $\in S_{\mathbb{N}}$ ($S_E$ with $E=\mathbb{N}$) consistent with $\{n \in \mathbb{N} : f(n) \not= n\}$ (the permutations that move only finitely many numbers) form a group?

**Answers**

**(1)** No, because $1$ isn't an element in the image.

**(2)**
$$
\underbrace{\cdots \mapsto 6 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 2}_\text{even} \mapsto \underbrace{1 \mapsto 3\mapsto 5\mapsto \cdots}_\text{odd}
$$
$$
n\mapsto \begin{cases}
n-2 & \text{if $n$ is even and $n\ne 2$}, \\
1 & \text{if }n=2, \\
n+2 & \text{if $n$ is odd.}
\end{cases}
$$
**(3)** If $f$ and $g$ move only finitely many numbers, then so does $f\circ g$.  Consider the intersection of the set of all fixed points of $f$ and the set of all fixed points of $g$.  That is the set of all numbers fixed by both $f$ and $g$.  Only finitely many numbers are not among these because the intersection of the complements of two finite sets is the complement of the union of the two finite sets, and the union of two finite sets is finite.  If $f$ moves only finitely many numbers, then so does $f^{-1}$.  Can we prove this last statement?  Then can we see that the two assertions here are all you need?

Comment: I don't understand question $2$. Is $E$ given in advance or not? Or should it be "is there a function $f\in S_\mathbb N$"?

Comment: Question 2 is correct. There is not $E$ given in advance. I have to find out a kind of function. Does the function is consistent with the question?

Comment: you don't understand. Question $2$ is not self-contained. If you do not tell me what $S_E$ is, then I cannot answer a question that asks "does there exist some function $f\in S_E$ such that this is true". For example, can you answer the question "Does an average gigimocado weigh more than five pounds?"

Comment: Pardon me, $E= \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Yes, I apologize! This is my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer $3$ is correct. You just need to prove the statement

> If $f$ only moves finitely many numbers, then $f^{-1}$ moves finitely many numbers.

This should be easy to see because if $f(x) = x$, then $f^{-1}(x) = x$ and vice versa. This means that the set $$A=\{n\in \mathbb N: f(n) =n\}$$

is equal to the set $$B=\{n\in\mathbb N: f^{-1}(n) = n\}$$

This means that $\mathbb N\setminus B = \mathbb N\setminus A$ which is a finite set.